# Convert base64 string to image and save

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to convert base64 image data into image file and to save it.

```
base64_image_str = request.POST.get('base64_image_str')
# it is smthg like: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDA......."

with open("newimage.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(base64_image_str.decode('base64'))
    f.close()
```

also tried:

```
f = open("newimage.png", "wb")
f.write(decodestring(base64_image_str))
f.close()
```

Image is being saved but it is corrupt and cannot open it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to get rid of the headers coming with the POST data.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary what headers? and how to do that?

Comment: In the first case , when you are using "with", there is no need to explicitly close that file, It will be automatically closed once you move out of that indented bock, and I will suggest you creating a new file to save the new image after decoding(removing "data:image/jpeg;base64,"), See if that helps you ?

Comment: This is a more clear answer with a full working example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267199/downloading-image-data-uris-from-webpages-via-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The start of the string, up to the first comma, is information added by POSTing the data, and as such is not part of the base64 encoding of your file.  So remove it before decoding.

Comment: i thought ``decodestring`` will do it for me, doesnot it?

Comment: If it did, would you be here?

Comment: dang it, didnot know it. it should be base64's decoders job basically. now it is working. in none of stackoverflow answers i saw a single answer/question which regards it. so i thought it is done automatically if i decode..

Comment: If decode worked the way you suggest, it would fail for base64 encodings that did *not* come from a POST request.

Answer (score 4):

As you see, the real image data starts off by a comma, you should strip off the remaining part,

```
base64_image_str = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDA......."

base64_image_str = base64_image_str[base64_image_str.find(",")+1:]
```