# Downloading Image Data URIs from Webpages via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I need to retrieve an image from a website using Python. However, the image is not in the form of a linked file, but as a GIF Data URI. How do I download this and store it in a .gif file?

Comment: Provide an example of what you are trying.

Comment: @Ross, I can't provide the URL to the webpage as it is sensitive, but : consider: <html> <img src="data:image/gif;base64,/........> </html>

Comment: You could post some Python code without the URL

Comment: So, I want to connect to this URL using python, and download the image as a .gif file.

Comment: @nivixzixer I haven't written any code yet, as I;m not sure how to approach this.

Comment: SO suggested this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357317/fetching-image-from-url-using-beautifulsoup however there, the tag is simply something like <img src="picture.jpg"> So you can use urllib to download the jpg file, but here it's a Data URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should get you going in the correct direction.

First, I'll assume you have retrieved the image uri data and it is saved in a python variable called img_data:

```
# Example
img_data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A...<lots of data>...k='
```

Now you'll need to decode the picture from base64 and save it to a file:

```
import base64

# Separate the metadata from the image data
head, data = img_data.split(',', 1)

# Get the file extension (gif, jpeg, png)
file_ext = head.split(';')[0].split('/')[1]

# Decode the image data
plain_data = base64.b64decode(data)

# Write the image to a file
with open('image.' + file_ext, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(plain_data)
```