# How to parse data-uri in python?

Tags: python, image, base64, data-uri

HTML image elements have [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) simplified format:

```
<img src='something'>
```

That something can be [`data-uri`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), for example:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...
```

Is there a standard way of parsing this with python, so that I get `content_type` and base64 data separated, or should I create my own parser for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267199/downloading-image-data-uris-from-webpages-via-beautifulsoup

Comment: Python 3 parses these natively https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.DataHandler

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Split the data URI on the comma to get the base64 encoded data without the header. Call `base64.b64decode` to decode that to bytes. Last, write the bytes to a file.

```
from base64 import b64decode

data_uri = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..."

# Python 2 and <Python 3.4
header, encoded = data_uri.split("base64,", 1)
data = b64decode(encoded)

# Python 3.4+
# from urllib import request
# with request.urlopen(data_uri) as response:
#     data = response.read()

with open("image.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Just splitting on first comma is not necessarily correct, the MIME may contain comma as well, for example: `data:video/webm; codecs=\"vp8, opus\";base64,GkXfowEAAAAAAAAfQoaBAUL3g...`

Comment: And quotes won't help, because this is also possible: `data:video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus;base64,GkXfo59...`

Answer (score 29):

Python since 3.4 has support for data-uri, under the hood using [`urllib.request.DataHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.DataHandler).

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen(data_uri) as response:
    data = response.read()
```

Answer (score 11):

w3lib (a library used by Scrapy) has a [function](https://github.com/scrapy/w3lib/blob/c1a030582ec30423c40215fcd159bc951c851ed7/w3lib/url.py#L294) to parse data uris:

```
>>> from w3lib.url import parse_data_uri
>>> parse_data_uri('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg==')
ParseDataURIResult(media_type='image/png', media_type_parameters={}, data=b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a')
```

Comment: the prettiest solution imho: short and produces well-structured result

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
import re
from lxml import html

BASE_NAME = "image_"

source_code = """<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" alt="Black dot" />"""

tree = html.fromstring(source_code)

for i,image in enumerate(tree.xpath('//img[contains(@src, "data:image")]/@src')):
    image_type, image_content = image.split(',', 1)
    image_type = re.findall('data:image\/(\w+);base64', image_type)[0]
    with open("{}{}.{}".format(BASE_NAME, i, image_type), "wb") as f:
        f.write(image_content.decode('base64'))
    print "[*] '{}' image found with content: {}\n".format(image_type, image_content)
```

**Output:**

```
[*] 'png' image found with content: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

[*] 'gif' image found with content: R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=
```

It will save every `base64` image within `<img>` tags, with their respective file extension:

Prefixed by **BASE_NAME** + **auto-increment digit(s) provided by `enumerate`** + **image_extension**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Correcting JRodDynamite's post:

```
from base64 import decodestring

png_arr= "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..."
png_arr = png_arr.split(",")
png_arr = png_arr[1]

fh = open("imageToSave.png", "wb")
fh.write(decodestring(png_arr))
fh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from urllib import request

def download(data_uri,name):

    with request.urlopen(data_uri) as response:
         data = response.read()

    with open(name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)

en="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images..."

src="data:image/png;base64,..."

download(en,"en")

download(src,"src")
```