# seve picture 'data:image/jpeg;base64' with python

Tags: python

How i can save or download this picture with python

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python

Comment: this image WhatsApp , and this post dont help me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem-in-python

Comment: Welcome, your question as it stand is super broad and unclear. Please feel free to edit your question to include more details. If you aren't sure how to improve your question, [MCVE] is a good place to start. Mainly what do you mean by how to save or download a picture? From what source are you trying to download from? What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870538/how-to-parse-data-uri-in-python

Answer (score 7):

Well, the start of the string (this part `data:image/jpeg;base64,`) tells you it is base64 encoded. So, you need to strip all that off and find the start the image, which is `/9j`, and just grab the image part which is the rest of the string.

```
b = b'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...'

z = b[b.find(b'/9'):]
```

Then you need base64 decode the result, and make it into a `BytesIO` object that PIL can read. Then read it into a PIL Image and save it:

```
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(z))).save('result.jpg')
```

So, the entire code will look like:

```
import base64
import io
from PIL import Image

# Initialise your data
b = b'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...'

z = b[b.find(b'/9'):]
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(z))).save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

**Keywords:** image, image processing, base64, b64, encode, encoded, decode, decoded, PIL, Pillow, Python