# Cannot load image, image url changes automatically url

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have a project at school with an e-commerce website that I need a large number of images to complete. So I consulted the code to download images from Youtube: John Watson Rooney
But I was having problem downloading half of the image Url changed to 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhFQAXAPAAANba3wAAACwAAAAAFQAXAAACFISPqcvtD6OctNqLs968+w+GolUAADs='
so I can't continue downloading.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import base64

def imagedown(url, folder):
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
    except:
        pass
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    images = soup.find_all('img', class_='styles__productImage--3ZNPD')
    for image in images:
        name = image['alt']
        link = image['src']
        with open(name.replace('/', '').replace('?', '').replace('=', '').replace('|', '') + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            im = requests.get(link)
            f.write(im.content)
            print('Writing: ', name)

imagedown('https://www.redbubble.com/shop/?gender=gender-men&iaCode=u-tees&page=2&query=dog&sortOrder=relevant&style=u-tee-regular-crew', 'Images')
```

[image]

I don't know where the error lies, please help me, thanks

Comment: You don't have to download this image. You already have it, it is just `base64` encoded. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870538/how-to-parse-data-uri-in-python) for solutions how to decode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the images you are trying to get are loaded dynamically when you scroll down the page so instead of using BeautifulSoup, you could try with a web scraping tool like Selenium:

First, install it with `pip install selenium`.

Download the Google chrome driver from the following [URL](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=91.0.4472.19) and save it, the latest version of Google Chrome must be installed in your computer as well.

And here is the script to download the images, as you can see, I implemented a loop to scroll down slowly to make sure the images are loaded before downloading them:

```
import os
import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# set path to your chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
# launch URL
driver.get("https://www.redbubble.com/shop/?gender=gender-men&iaCode=u-tees&page=2&query=dog&sortOrder=relevant&style=u-tee-regular-crew")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

# Scroll the page slowly by sending down arrow keys and pausing between each stroke
scroll_pause_time = 0.05
scroll_strokes = 400

for i in range(scroll_strokes):
    # Send arrow down
    body.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

# find images
images = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('styles__productImage--3ZNPD')
save_folder = 'c:/temp/images/'

for image in images:
    name = image.get_attribute('alt')
    link = image.get_attribute('src')
    ext =  os.path.splitext(link)[1]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, save_folder + name.replace('/', '').replace('?', '').replace('=', '').replace('|', '').replace('"', '') + ext)

# close browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, your way is absolutely optimal and effective ♥

Answer (score 0):

Those images are encoded as base64 strings so you don't need to download them, you can simply save them as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os
import re

def imagedown(url, folder):
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
    except:
        pass
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    images = soup.find_all('img', class_='styles__productImage--3ZNPD')
    for image in images:
        name = image['alt']
        link = image['src']
        ext = None
        data = None

        if link.startswith('data'):
            with urlopen(link) as response:
                if link.startswith('data:image/gif'):
                    ext = '.gif'
                data = response.read()
        else:
            ext = os.path.splitext(link)[1]
            data = requests.get(link).content
               
        with open(name.replace('/', '').replace('?', '').replace('=', '').replace('|', '') + ext, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)
            print('Writing: ', name)

imagedown('https://www.redbubble.com/shop/?gender=gender-men&iaCode=u-tees&page=2&query=dog&sortOrder=relevant&style=u-tee-regular-crew', 'Images')
```

Comment: Is there any way that can help me to download the image as a jpg, I can't view the image as a gif. It's weird that when I inspect I can still see the normal url but when using python it's base64 encoded.

Comment: Can you send one of the URLs?

Comment: https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1911237172.8285/ssrco,classic_tee,mens,101010:01c5ca27c6,front_alt,square_product,600x600.jpg
This is one of the product URLs that I use to download

Comment: Yeah, but the jpeg got changed to gif somehow in the behind productions. That problem prevented me from continuing to download the image

Comment: Sorry for the delay, can you help me please. I don't know why the url was changed to a gif tag.

Comment: Do you have to use BeautifulSoup, maybe it will be easier with selenium.

Comment: See my new answer for a working solution ,-)