# How to get file type from complex image URL in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to get image file extensions from image URLs like below:

```
from os.path import splitext
image = ['ai','bmp','gif','ico','jpeg','jpg','png','ps','psd','svg','tif','tiff','webp']
def splitext_(path, extensions):
    for ext in extensions:
        if path.endswith(ext):
            return path[:-len(ext)], path[-len(ext):]
    return splitext(path)

val = "https://dkstatics-public.digikala.com/digikala-products/9f4cb4e049e7a5d48c7bc22257b5031ee9a5eae8_1602179467.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_300,w_300/quality,q_80"
#val = "https://www.needmode.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%85-%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%B1.webp"
ex_filename, ext = splitext_(val,image)
ex_extension = ext.replace(".", "", 1)
im_extension = ex_extension.lower()

print(im_extension)
```

**The problem is this method not working on URLs like below**

```
https://dkstatics-public.digikala.com/digikala-products/9f4cb4e049e7a5d48c7bc22257b5031ee9a5eae8_1602179467.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_300,w_300/quality,q_80
```

The result is nothing for the example image URL, but it's working on normal URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: here how to manage multiple extension.

For this, it's better to use the @Andrej Kesely answer for parsing the url. Working on the url as string only will lead to have the host split and it's harder to manage (you would go to rewrite `urlparse`).

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

val = "https://dkstatics-public.digikala.com/digikala-products/9f4cb4e049e7a5d48c7bc22257b5031ee9a5eae8_1602179467.tar.gz?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_300,w_300/quality,q_80"

parsed_url = urlparse(val)

extension = parsed_url.path.rsplit(".")[1:]
print(extension)
```

First answer.
Here how you can do:

```py
val = "https://dkstatics-public.digikala.com/digikala-products/9f4cb4e049e7a5d48c7bc22257b5031ee9a5eae8_1602179467.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_300,w_300/quality,q_80"
print(val.split("?")[0].split(".")[-1])
```

You split first on the question mark and keeping the url part, not the parameters. And then you split on the dot and keep the last part which is the extension.

It won't work with multiple extensions like `tar.gz`, you would only have `gz`.

Comment: Superfast and useful, Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's working with tar.gz if we change the for to  => for ext in ['.tar.gz', '.tar.bz2']:

Comment: I edit my answer with multiple extensions. In my answer and also the one of @Andrej Kesely, we don't suppose what are searched extension.

Answer (score 3):

Use `urlparse` to parse the URL:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

val = "https://dkstatics-public.digikala.com/digikala-products/9f4cb4e049e7a5d48c7bc22257b5031ee9a5eae8_1602179467.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_300,w_300/quality,q_80"

parsed_url = urlparse(val)

extension = parsed_url.path.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)[-1]
print(extension)
```

Prints:

```
jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is which method is better ?  use splittext or urlparse ? and why ?

Comment: @Martin `urlparse` is standard method how to break URL to various parts (e.g. scheme (`http://` or `https://`), location, query paramaters etc. If your URL you're trying to parse don't change much, `str.split` is OK for ad-hoc parsing.

Comment: I used this method in my code. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what to do with this kind of encoded image URLs.
data:image/webp;base64,UklGRrIOAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAAQAAAAzwcA5wMAQUxQSGQAAAABBxARERASJP4/bySi/xn/+c9//vOf//znP//5z3/+85///Oc///nPf/7zn//85z//+c9//vOf//znP//5z3/+85///Oc///nPf/7zn//85z//+c9//vOf//znP//5z3/+8/8FVlA4ICgOAADwqgGdASrQB+gDP/3+/3+/uzayIAgD8D+JaW7h

Comment: @Martin That's data-url. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870538/how-to-parse-data-uri-in-python